# Impossible to install Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

When i try to install VisualStudio 2022 i get this error message : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYcP4.png)

here is my log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHVvw.png)

I checked that all users have write and read rights on the log file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI6K5.png)

I don't know where the problem came from ..

Comment: Have you tried restarting Windows? Best to add text to your question as text and not an image. It's easier to read and can be translated when necessary.

Comment: It is possible you have a higher version installed. check your features and software if it is already installed. I would remove it if it is installed so this new installation can just cover it all.